# Multiple config rest server in CI

Tags: codeigniter, rest, restful-authentication

I have trouble to access more than one config rest server in CI.. I have 2 rest will I want to access, 
`http://localhost/sia/Rest_server` and `http://localhost/sia/Rest_physics`.
but I do not know how to access the rest of the servers in a single controller.

This is the code:

```
public function __construct(){
    parent::__construct();
    $this->load->library('rest');
    $config = array('server' => 'http://localhost/sia/Rest_server/');
    $this->rest->initialize($config);
}
public function inputMhs($jurusan = NULL){
    if (!in_array ($jurusan, array ('ilkom', 'fisika'))){
        show_404();
        return;
    }
    $this->load->view('admin/header');
    $data['jurusan'] = $jurusan;
    $data['data'] = $this->rest->get('ambilmhs', 'json');
    $this->load->view('admin/v_inputmhs',$data);
    $this->load->view('admin/footer');
}
```